# Problema al llamar función con atributo text javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Tengo un problema al llamar a la función que tengo en una etiqueta  `<a>`.
No estoy seguro si es por los campos que estoy enviando.

```
<a onclick="verNoticia('<?php echo $item[0]; ?>','<?php echo $item[1]; ?>','\' <?php echo $item[3]; ?> \'','<?php echo $item[5]; ?>');">
                                <button  type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-sm' style="margin-left: 10px;">
                                    <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </button>
                                </a>
```

Le pongo los slash en el item[3] ya que es un texto el que mando, pero aun así me sale error.

[image: Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token]

Comment: Al parecer tienes mal formado el html, te sobran las comillas  ( \' ). No sé que has querido hacer con eso pero eso hace que no te forme bien los String dentro de la función verNoticia.

Comment: Por lo que lei, como era un texto con simbolos lo que queria enviar, no se podia enviar asi simplemente entre comillas, por eso use eso.
Pero lo solucione enviandolo mediante un JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre solucionarlo, enviando el texto mediante un JSON, en la funcion.